# How do I run a EXE Go executable from within IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, go

I have a Go program which I'm working on in IntelliJ IDEA on a Windows machine. The program's structure is a little unconventional (don't want to go into detail here as its besides the point) because of which I first have to compile the program using the following command:

`go build -o cli.exe`

And then I can run `cli.exe` directly in the command prompt.

But how do I configure the run configuration in IntelliJ IDEA so that it doesn't mind running a Windows executable ? Because if I try to tell it to run an EXE file as it's run configuration, it gives me error "Main file is invalid"

How do I solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a **file** name (not a **folder** name) in field **File** on **Run/Debug Configuration** window (In IntelliJ IDEA go to menu Run->Edit Configuration...->*your_configuration*). That was my case.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to install the Bash plugin on Windows, then create a run configuration using the Bash plugin, and just run your executable from a script.

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't see an option in IntelliJ IDEA's Run Configuration dialog which allows you to run a Bash script in place of a Go executable.

Comment: what i mean is you can have your bash script call the Go executable.

Comment: This is what I use to run powershell commands from a run configuration as well. `Script: #  | Interpreter path: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe | Interpreter options: <your command> `

Answer (score 0):

Create a Go Application run configuration and that should work. You can choose to run either a file or a package. If you would share more details then the answer would be more complete. If you still have an issue with this, please open an issue to the bug tracker and I'll be able to help out (please follow the issue template there).

Comment: I had tried running the EXE through 'Go Application' run configuration too, but it also didn't allow me to run an EXE. That is, I got the same "Main file is invalid" error.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of your run configuration.